# Copy a class-type element by index from one vector to another c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, copy

I have a class `Atom`:

```
class Atom {
        public:
                Atom();
                string name; string mol_name; string MF; // element, molecule name, movable/frozen
                int mol_id;
                double m,eps,sig,C=0.0,V=0.0,K=0.0,E=0.0;
                int ID;
                map <string,double> pos; // equivalent of python FM1.9 "x"
                map <string,double> prevpos;
                map <string,double> force; // "    " F
                map <string,double> vel; // v
                map <string,double> acc; // a
                map <string,double> dip; // dipole
                map <string,double> efield; // electric field;
};
```

And a vector of such atoms `atoms`:

`vector<Atom> atoms` which is populated with different atoms (0,1,2...) and respective variables e.g. `name`.

I want to copy, e.g. `atoms[3]` to another vector `tmp_atoms`. I'm trying:

`std::copy ( atoms.begin() + 3, atoms.begin() + 3, tmp_atoms.begin());`

to no avail, because when I try to access `tmp_atoms[0]` or `tmp_atoms[3]` I get a segmentation fault. My access attempt is:
`printf("Make sure tmp_atoms[0] is a thing: %s \n", tmp_atoms[0].name.c_str()); // program seg. faults here`

I think there is a special case for copying class-types, because this should be correct in the case of, e.g., vectors of integers. Please assist!

Comment: explain downvote?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: this is about as mcve as I can make it. Goal = copy a vector element, which is itself a class instance, to another vector

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` and at least one `#include`.  Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight will consider for next time. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [std::back_inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/):

```
std::copy ( atoms.begin()+3, atoms.begin() + 4,
            std::back_inserter( tmp_atoms));
```

Or simply

```
 tmp_atoms.push_back(atoms[3]);
```

Comment: still seg-faulting. It doesn't seem to copy the class contents, I think. When I do `printf("Make sure tmp_atoms[0] is a thing: %s \n", tmp_atoms[0].name.c_str());` the seg-fault appears.

Comment: I made a small edit, please check it

Comment: The use of `back_inserter` worked as in your first example, ty.

Comment: (I tried this before but did not have the right syntax on `back_inserter`)

Answer (score 0):

The code `std::copy ( atoms.begin() + 3, atoms.begin() + 3, tmp_atoms.begin());` uses the same iterator value (`atoms.begin() + 3`) for both the start and the end of the range - which means, you're copying an empty range.

Also, if you're planning to use "copy" as above, it's your responsibility to ensure that your target iterator (`tmp_atoms.begin()`) points to a valid position within tmp_atoms.  If tmp_atoms is empty, you can't copy elements into it without resizing it first (for example, using an inserting iterator, like the other reply suggested, or something like `vector::push_back()`).

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting, but thanks for the information. Didn't know the same index will result in no copy.

Comment: It's a common convention with iterators.  Any time you deal with an API that takes two iterators, the first iterator points to the first item from the sequence, while the second iterator ("end") points one-past-the last item (and doesn't have to be dereferencable).

Comment: No idea about downvoting.  But about your code sample - "verifiable" means code somebody could compile and run directly, without adding any "include" statements, "main" function, etc, - in other words, without making any assumptions about the rest of your code.